# Trying to build a create-react-app project with expo, throws error about react-native

Tags: reactjs, expo, create-react-app

I've created my react app using create-react-app, and was trying to use expo, but its throwing errors when I try and build it using `expo build:android`:

```
Error: Can't find react-native in package.json dependencies
Error: React Native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
```

Do I need to start over with a react-native project, or is there a way to continue on and get this project published?

Comment: What node version are you running?

Comment: I was at 10.16.2, but have since upgraded to 13.5.0

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create your project using the [expo docs](https://expo.io/learn) :

```
npm install expo-cli --global

expo init my-new-project
cd my-new-project
expo start
```

Comment: Going this route, will report back if everything goes as planned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Remove node_modules folder.
- run "yarn install".
- run "expo start".

This looks like a similar issue on this github error

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/248